# How can I add audio files on a (Mapbox) map embedded with <iframe srcdoc>?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to set up a sound mapping system: built with Mapbox and embedded in another website which only allows `<iframe>` to avoid conflicting scripts. On one hand I need to intervene on the map's code and on the other, respect the embedding constrain. The problem seems to be at the `.setHTML()` function within `<iframe srcdoc>`. But being new to coding, I cannot really tell.

Here was my approach: after creating a map style and tilesets in Mapbox, I used `<iframe srcdoc>` to inject some code for: displaying popups, getting sets' map features, or adding right to left support scripts.

```
var feature = features[0];

var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
    .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
    .setHTML('<h3>' + feature.properties.title + '</h3><p>' +  feature.properties.description + '</p><audio controls> <source src="' + feature.properties.urls + '" type="audio/ogg">' + '<source src="' + feature.properties.urls + '" type="audio/mp3">' + '</audio>')
    .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
    .addTo(map);
});
```

I expect the injected code to draw my audio files from Mapbox features  and display audio players for a fully interactive experience.

Comment: Your question implies that you aren't achieving the desired result, but it's not clear what this approach _is_ doing. Would you mind sharing the result you got instead of the actual audio controls?